# What is the difference between Sada-Shiva (सदाशिव) & Maha-Sada-Shiva (महासदाशिव)? And which scriptures discuss their iconography?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, iconography

God Sada-Shiva (सदाशिव) is depicted as a five-faced deity, with 10 hands and 15 eyes. As per Kamikagama he must be of white color, as shown below -

> [image]
>
> **Sadashiva (सदाशिव)**

---

While God Maha-Sada-Shiva (महासदाशिव) is depicted as an 25 headed deity, with 75 eyes, abd 50 arms.

> [image]
>
> **Maha-Sadashiva (महासदाशिव)**

---

Although, the prefix 'Maha (महा)' is generally added to a deity's name to indicate greatness or grandiose as an embellishments, but sometimes, the prefix does makes a difference.
For example - Sometimes difference between the Vaishnava Lakshmi, and the Shaktas Mulaprakriti Mahalakshmi, or Shambhu and Maha-Shambhu in the Shaivite, or Vishnu and Maha-Vishnu et al.

In any case, clearly, in case of Sada-Shiva and Maha-Sada-Shiva we can see a clear Iconographical distinction, even if they might be manifestation of the same Supreme Parama-Shiva.

**Question is -**

What's the difference between them, in powers or their governing principles, and Iconography. Which scriptures discuss their iconography and differentiates between the two?

---

**Note:**

Kindly Note, this question is NOT a duplicate of this question -

[What is the meaning behind Shiva with 26 heads and 52 hands?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/what-is-the-meaning-behind-shiva-with-26-heads-and-52-hands)

My question seeks comparative analysis on both the Iconographical aspects, motifs and themes behind the two deities. Also, I want answers from Aagaamas and Silpasastras which might discuss both the deities.

The answer to the above question on the other hand uses Wikipedia and blogs to answer an slightly related part of my question which is not what I seek, at all.

Comment: Who is Shambhu and Maha Shambhu in your question?

Comment: So MahaShambhu is the consort of Parashakti Lalitha, in the Shaiva-Sakta traditions. Basically, the "higher-form" of Rudra, if you may say. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Okk..I want to read more about Shambhu and Maha Shambhu, could you tell me where are they mentioned in puranas?

Comment: I think he's mentioned in the Brahmanda Purana, in that episode of demon Bhandasura, I can't recall exactly. and maybe in the Skanda Purāṇa too. He maybe mentioned in more details in the Aagamas @LSSJBroly

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto can you kindly please explain why this question has been closed, and who closed it, suddenly without any due process? (it's showing none). My question asks for answers based on Agamas and the difference between the two deities, while the Question which has been duplicated gives answers from Wikipedias and Blogs. How is the duplicate? Kindly see to this problem and Re-open the question, please.