# 5 Incarnations of MahaDeva

Tags: mahabharata, shiva

In the Mahabarata are referred five different incarnations (Vamadevascha ) of Mahadeva:

Sadyojata of White Colour ;
Vama Deva of Red Complexion;
Agoresha of blue complexion;
Tatpurusha of Yellow Complexion;
Ishana as Sada Shiva of Ash Complexion who is the Embodiment of Vidya , Creative Energy and Sublimity;

Where is possible to find more informations about them?

Comment: see if these help little bit : 1. [shiva avataras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/why-did-lord-shiva-take-44-avatars-if-his-primary-role-is-to-be-the-destroyer/16687#16687), 2.[shiva symbolism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13530/20129) 3. [five faces of a shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20056/20129)